# Incorrect graph output using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, option-clash

I am trying to plot the graph of y=3^x+2 with domain [-2,2], using the pgfplots package.

It is part of a larger document which involves quite a few packages, as you can see from the MWE (below). I have included the full list in case a package clash or ordering issue is responsible for my problem.

Running the MWE, however, the output appears to be incorrect; for example when x=0, y=2, when it should be the case that y=3.

I would like to understand what I have done wrong that causes the to happen, and how to go about correcting it.

My LaTeX knowledge is low, and my TikZ/pgfplots knowledge lower still(!), and tends to be quite hacky, so please go easy in your comments if there are any glaringly obviously mistakes or distasteful coding in my example.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed} 
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[restrict x to domain=-2:2,
                        axis y line=middle, 
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        xlabel=$x$,
                        ylabel={$y =3^x+2$},
                        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.08,0.125)}},
                        y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.4,1.15)}},
                        xmin=-2.2,
                        xmax=2.2,
                        ymax=11.5,
                        ]
                \addplot[blue]{add(pow(3,x),2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addplot[blue] {2+pow(3,x)}` ?  (There is a missing parenthesis in your expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is correct --- your `y` axis starts from 2, look:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[restrict x to domain=-2:2,
                        axis y line=middle, 
                        axis x line=bottom,
                        xlabel=$x$,
                        ylabel={$y =3^x+2$},
                        x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.08,0.125)}},
                        y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.4,1.15)}},
                        xmin=-2.2,
                        xmax=2.2,
                        ymax=11.5,
                        extra y ticks = {3},
                        % ymin=0,
                        ]
                        \addplot[blue, samples=100]{2+pow(3,x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you add `ymin=0` you have probably what you expected:

[image]

(BTW, as you can see, just loading `pgfplots` suffices for the MWE).

Comment: D'oh! Thank you so much @Rmano much for clarifying. I knew the answer was staring me in the face and was likely to be trivial(!) -- it usually is with me. I just couldn't see it!